# Force IE to ignore other css style sheets

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have nearly finished the site i am working on, however IE doesn't accept some of my animations.

I know i can specify a IE only sheet:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/stylesheet.css"></link>
<![endif]-->
```

However IE still runs the other style sheet, Does anyone know a way to force IE to ignore a css style sheet?

regards,
Jimy

Comment: Be aware that IE10 doesn't support Conditional Comments.

Comment: Great lol, does Microsoft try to be a pain or it's just a by-product?

Answer (score 1):

Since CSS stands for cascading style sheet the idea for these conditional sheets is to override the "normal css"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/normalstylesheet.css"></link>
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/iestylesheet.css"></link>
<!--[endif]-->
```

Everything in the former would be over wrote by the latter stylesheet. If you have another specific reason to omit something though you can always use this.

```
<!--[if !IE]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/notiestylesheet.css"></link>
<!--[endif]-->
```

Comment: If i place my main css first, then the above code, and i set a red background to my IE css and hit refresh, the screen flashes red but immediately reverts back to my main css. Any other ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you're missing something, could you provide a Fiddle to demonstrate this?

Comment: While i couldn't get IE to point to a seperate css, i was able to hide specific css styles that IE doesn't accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
<!--[if !IE]-->
  IE ignores this
<!--[endif]-->
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work for me, both chrome and IE could see that text, though a slightly different variant in each.

Comment: Check generated page source.